# Load HTML file, edit content inside a tag, and save changes to HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm working on a project where you need to load an HTML file, edit some content in a tag, and then save those changes back to the same file without affecting any other the other content.

Here's what my markup looks like:

```php
<?php 
    session_start();
    $page_title = "Hello world";

    include "../includes/header.php"
?>
<div data-content></div>
<?php 
    include "../includes/footer.php";
?>
```

And then using ajax - I send any content that's been added to the `<div data-content></div>`

The issue I'm running into is trying to save this new content to the existing HTML file without affecting the rest of the HTML file.

The goal is to make a visual CMS so if anyone has any better suggestions - I'm open to pivoting and taking a better route.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Hint: you're probably going to be using [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="public" action="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><label for="file">File Name:</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></p>
    <br/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Parsing" name="sendData"/></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
//test if the file is selected
if(!isset($_POST['sendData'])) exit;
//get file name
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
//be sure this file is html file
$ext = explode('.', $filename);
if($ext[1] != 'html'){
    echo '<br>bad file type, it must be html file';
    exit;
}
//upload the file to temp area
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
//read the file
$file = @fopen($filename, 'r');
if($file === false){
    echo 'Error when reading the file';
    exit;  
}
//reading line by line
$output ='';
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $output .= str_replace('<img', '<svg', $line);
}
fclose($file);
//write the new file
$result = file_put_contents($filename, $output);
echo $result;
if(!$result){
    echo 'faild';
}else{
    echo 'success <br/>';
    $load_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $load_link = str_replace('pars.php', '', $load_link); 
    $load_link .= $filename;   
    echo '<a href='.$load_link.'>See the results</a><br>';
}


?>
```

Comment: Here you are replacing <img tag with the <svg tag